# REG_MATCH function in Informatica - Identify a pattern

Tags: regex, informatica

Can you please help me identify a regex pattern for the below set of strings

1921 abc abc abc **1k**

4320 abcs abc Apt **201b**

1250 abcd Ave Apt **3c**

**61a** abcd Ave

**1b** abcd Ave

**39r** abcd Rd

**16w750** abcd Ave

abc **12a**

The ask is to identify if a sentence contain a single character before, after or in between digits.

```
\d[A-Za-z]\d|\d[A-Za-z]|^[A-Za-z]\d
```

This is something I tried, but didn't work :)

*Only a single character should be present.There can be many numbers.*

Comment: Try `([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*` or `(?:[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z0-9]*`

Comment: 4320 abc Blvd Apt 201b - It should work
4320 abc Blvd Apt 201bb - It should not work

Comment: Then maybe `\b\d+[a-z]\d*\b` - https://regex101.com/r/cTUJ4y/1

Comment: Just read you are probably using the string literals in Informatica, so you will need to double backslashes, i.e. `\\b\\d+[a-z]\\d*\\b`.

Comment: You need to keep in mind how regular expressions work in Informatica. It's not the general, common way. You need to write a pattern that will always match the full input, divide it into sequences and extract the desired sequence.  Read the docs: https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-5/transformation-language-reference/functions/reg_extract.html

Examples provided by @WiktorStribiżew are working fine, just not the Informatica-way. The difference is, they match a part of the input.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really supply a *precise* definition but this does match your pattern:

```
\b(?=\d+[a-zA-Z][0-9]*)([0-9a-zA-Z]*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HxSekS/1)

If there is a possibility of non digits starting (which is not in your example) then use an alteration:

```
\b(?=(?:[a-zA-Z]\d+[a-zA-Z]*)|(?:\d+[a-zA-Z]\d*))[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dIoFcY/1)

Comment: There can be only one character and n numbers , like a1, 1a1, 11a, 123a2312, 112a

Comment: Remove the `+` then.

Comment: There can be non digits starting.

Comment: I think the edit captured you comments. Try it!

Comment: \b(?=(?:[a-zA-Z]\d+[a-zA-Z]*)|(?:\d+[a-zA-Z]\d*))[a-zA-Z0-9]* is picking "a123def",16w750RST also even after removing +

Comment: Please be specific about what **should** and **should not** match.

Answer (score 0):

The [`REG_MATCH`](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-5/transformation-language-reference/functions/reg_match.html) function needs the whole string to be matched, so you can use

```sql
REG_MATCH( subject, '.*\b\d+[a-z]\d*\b.*' )
```

*Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more characters other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `[a-z]` - a lowercase ASCII letter
- `\d*` - zero or more digits
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `.*` - any zero or more characters other than line break chars as many as possible

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qHIMS0/1).

Comment: When using `REG_EXTRACT` to actually get the value, you will need a capturing group, i.e. `REG_MATCH( subject, '.*\b(\d+[a-z]\d*)\b.*' )` (by default, the first group value will be extracted, else, provide the group number as the third argument).

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
\b(\d*[a-zA-Z]\d+|\d+[a-zA-Z]\d*)\b
```

You will need to match it and then extract the second matching group (the middle one)  You can check it [here](https://regex101.com/r/rbcfav/1).